# org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/var/database/schema/label/lucene/write.lock

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j, cypher

I am just getting this error 
Error Log :
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/var/database/schema/label/lucene/write.lock
    org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
    org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:1098)
    org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterFactories$1.create(IndexWriterFactories.java:44)
    org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.init(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:301)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:474)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
    org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:337)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:165)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:310)
    org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:100)
    org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
    org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
    com.util.Neo4JConnectionHelper.getDBInstance(Neo4JConnectionHelper.java:31)
    com.test.CreateNode.migrateData1(CreateNode.java:42)
    com.test.CreateNode.doGet(CreateNode.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

I have created my database with java code and using library,So Please check if i turn off the server directly so How i could resume this database when i getting this error on it.

How to remove write lock from file by code Please share your view on it.

Answer (score 5):

Are you running a second instance of Neo4j on the same directory?

If not make a backup copy of your graphdb directory, remove `/var/database/schema/label/lucene/write.lock` and retry.

Comment: No i have stop my server first then restart the server but getting this error on it

Comment: Did you remove the .lock file?

Comment: No If i remove the file then it should not generate any other error

Comment: Is that a question or a fact?

Comment: i am not able to access it please give me another way how can i achieve this